# How to make Event Listeners work with external Javascript File?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-listener

I have these simple files -

```js
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click",function(){
 alert("Did it work?");
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myevents.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button id="btn2">Please Work!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

which work correctly here and also on jsFiddle, but when I run this on my computer locally, the EventListener won't work! I've been trying to fix this all day and no success. What is the problem? I just cannot seem to figure it out!

Comment: Put the `<script>` tag right before the `</body>` closing tag.

Comment: @Pointy: It worked. What is the reason for this? Normal javascript runs fine when `<script>` tags are inside `<head>`?

Comment: @Sidsec9 See the error console. If Pointy's hypothesis is correct (it is my first 'hunch' too) then `getElementById("btn2")` will return null and the line to add the event listener throws a TypeError - and thus the event handler, which is never added, can never be triggered. (JavaScript code can be in head; what *can't* be done is accessing an element *before it exists*.)

Comment: @Sidsec9 browsers build the DOM incrementally as the HTML is parsed. When a `<script>` tag is seen, the contents are evaluated immediately. Thus, your code was running *before* the button had been added to the DOM.

Comment: Look at your JavaScript console. Look at the error message you get.